# How to write -o permission into /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, ntfs, fstab

Set usermap.

```
sudo ntfsusermap /dev/sdb2
#assign user as www-data
#assign group as www-data
```

Mount ntfs partition `/dev/sdb2` with `/mnt/winntfs`.

```
sudo ntfs-3g -o permissions  /dev/sdb2  /mnt/winntfs
```

Now i can use `chmod` for directory in `/mnt/winntfs`.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
ls -al   /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
total 38
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 17 20:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root     root     4096 Aug 17 20:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 17 20:03 analyse
```

I want to make the mount configure in `/etc/fstab`.

```
sudo blkid | grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="winntfs" UUID="284A29774A2942C4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="292c184b-766f-4036-8fa0-5bcd936b85c2
sudo vim  /etc/fstab
UUID=284A29774A2942C4   /mnt/winntfs  ntfs-3g rw ,auto , umask=0022 ,permissions 0 0
```

Reboot and enter into my os,

```
ls -al  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
total 38
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:03 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:03 analyse
sudo chmod -R 755  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
ls -al  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
total 38
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:03 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:03 analyse
```

The fact is that to set `permissions` and `umask=0022` in `/etc/fstab` can't use `chmod`,how to write proper `/etc/fstab` to make `chmod` to be used after reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put so many random spaces in your fstab:

```
UUID=284A29774A2942C4   /mnt/winntfs  ntfs-3g rw,auto,umask=0022,permissions  0 0
```

Fstab entries are six *whitespace-separated* fields, which means they cannot have any whitespace internally. Whether it's the device name or the directory path or the options list, you cannot have spaces or tabs in the value because that separates it into multiple fields.

Comment: The setting can use `chmod` ,instead of `chown` ,why `chown` can't be used with the setting line?

Comment: UUID=284A29774A2942C4   /mnt/winntfs  ntfs-3g rw,auto,permissions  0 0

Comment: The above setting can make both `chmod` and `chown` take effect.